# How to use .wrapAll() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, each, wrapall

I need to find all the p tags inside all the `div`s with a class of `someClass` and wrap them with another `div`. This is how the beginning mark up would look like:

```html
<div class="someClass">
  // Lots of different tags generated by the site
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="someClass">
  // Lots of different tags generated by the site
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Would turn into:

```html
<div class="someClass">
  // Lots of different tags generated by the site
  <div class="bla">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="someClass">
  // Lots of different tags generated by the site
  <div class="bla">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? When I try using `.each()`: for each `div` with a class of `someClass` wrap all the `p` tags, but it just wraps them all together in the top `div`.

Comment: Can you post your code? Your approach sounds right.

Comment: I've posted an example here: 

http://pastebin.me/30acb260acc142dd0c9979aca9812390

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
$('div.someClass p').wrapAll(...);
```

Or this?

```
$('div.someClass').each(function() {
  $(this).find('p').wrapAll(...);
});
```

**Edit**

After looking at the code you posted, it appears to be a syntax issue.  You need quotes in this line:

```
$(this).find('p').wrapAll(<div class='toggle'></div>);
```

It should be:

```
$(this).find('p').wrapAll("<div class='toggle'></div>");
```

Comment: I've tried that and similar things. It's really giving me a headache now!! I've posted an example of the problem on :

http://pastebin.me/30acb260acc142dd0c9979aca9812390

Comment: @John - your code *almost* works, just need to change the `<div>` class to `someClass`. Here's a Working Demo - http://jsbin.com/oxexe add **/edit** to the URL to see the code

Comment: @Russ:  I'm not sure what you mean.  The edited section is a modification of a line within his code, where he is inserting the "toggle" div.  It shouldn't be changed to "someclass".

Comment: @John - check out the case of the CSS class of the `<div>` in your selector compared to the CSS class of the `<div>` already in the HTML page in the question - you have `someclass` whereas the question has `someClass`. According to the HTML 4.01 spec, class and names are case-sensitive (although some browsers are not compliant with the spec) - http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/viewsource/2001/css-class-id/

Comment: Ah.  I hadn't tested it or intended it to be copy-paste worthy.  Thanks for pointing that out, though.